# Null value in column "title" of relation "blog" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, express, node-pg-pool

I'm building a little blog using express js for the backend, but I'm facing an issue: I get this error in the console

> null value in column "contentblog" of relation "blog" violates not-null constraint

Code:

```
const connection = require('../DatabaseConnection/db')

module.exports.Add = function (req, res) {
    const blog = {
        title: req.body.title,
        contentBlog: req.body.contentBlog,
    }
    connection.query('INSERT INTO blog(contentBlog) values($1)', [blog.contentBlog], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                status: false,
                message: 'there are some errors with the query'
            })
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.json({
                status: true,
                data: results,
                message: 'Post has been added successfully'
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I need more information but it looks like the `req.body.contentBlog` is `null` or `undefined` however in your database you have this set up as a foreign key which cannot be `NULL`

Comment: CREATE TABLE blog (
 blog_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 contentBlog VARCHAR ( 500 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

Comment: its undefined as u said

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.body is undefined - expressjs with postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533660/req-body-is-undefined-expressjs-with-postgres-database)

Comment: @dailycoding - okay great. I've added an answer for you to accept for others who are looking too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a `null` or `undefined` variable into your postgresql table.

Check the value of `req.body.contentBlog`.